# Invoking EventHandler generic, TargetParameterCountException

Tags: c#, generics, invoke, event-handling

I have a DirectoryMonitor class which works on another thread.
It has the following events declared:

```
public class DirectoryMonitor
{
    public event EventHandler<MonitorEventArgs> CreatedNewBook;
    public event EventHandler ScanStarted;
    ....
}

public class MonitorEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Book Book { get; set; }
}
```

There is a form using that monitor, and upon receiving the events, it should update the display.

Now, this works:

```
    void DirectoryMonitor_ScanStarted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(new EventHandler(this.DirectoryMonitor_ScanStarted));
        }
        else {...}
    }
```

But this throws `TargetParameterCountException`:

```
    void DirectoryMonitor_CreatedNewBook(object sender, MonitorEventArgs e)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(new EventHandler<MonitorEventArgs>(this.DirectoryMonitor_CreatedNewBook));
        }
        else {...}
    }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Invoke method excepts to receive a `System.Delegate` instance which can be invoked without passing any additional parameters.  The delegate created by using `DirectoryMonitor_ScanStarted` requires 2 parameters and hence you get the exception when it's used.

You need to create a new delegate which wraps the call and arguments together.

```
MethodInvoker del = () => this.DirectoryMonitor_ScanStarted(sender,e);
Invoke(del);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Though i still don't quite understand why the First event is fired OK, but the second ones throws the exception.

Comment: I had the same strange behavior. One Invoke worked and the other not. The "key" was that the working Invoke was using a simple EventArgs-derived class without any additions and the non-working Invoke was using an EventArgs-derived class with some additional fields (like your MonitorEventArgs). It looks like the first case somehow gets ignored during reflection, but the second not.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the parameters:-

```
void DirectoryMonitor_ScanStarted(object sender, MonitorEventArgs e)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(new EventHandler<MonitorEventArgs>(DirectoryMonitor_ScanStarted), sender, e);
        }
        else {...}
    }
```

For reasons not clear to me (probably due to COM legacy) it's permissible to omit parameters when using a generic event, but not when using a user defined EventArg type.